# Display text and buttons in Variable Length Paragraph

Tags: ios

For my app I have a "summary" paragraph that will be of variable length depending on a number of factors.  Certain parts will also be buttons to other information.  For example: Your flight #1234(button) from New York to San Francisco (another different button) is On time.  Not only is the information variable, but what factors are displayed.  For example sometimes there might be a connection to display. Where should I start looking for methods to do this?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't look for the methods, create them! :)

Comment: Any idea of what frameworks I should use or some sort of a starting point?

Comment: I believe all of what you want to do should be possible using only UIKit; no other frameworks necessary :)